# @EnableAutoConfiguration on AbstractIntegrationTest possible?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Having lots of Integration-Test Implementations like this:

```
// no @Annotations at all
class SomeIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
  ...
}
```

using (Spring Boot 1.5, JUnit 5)

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {CoreConfiguration.class, RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
  ...
}
```

this is always failing with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available
```

unless I annotate *every* IntegrationTest-Implementation with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration    
class SomeIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
 ...
}
```

I wonder why I cannot `@EnableAutoConfiguration` the `AbstractIntegrationTest` and be done with it.
(When doing so, it fails with `IllegalArgumentException: No auto-configuration attributes found. Is package.SomeIntegrationTest annotated with EnableAutoConfiguration?`)

Our normal Apps look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({CoreConfiguration.class, OtherConfiguration.class})
public class WebApp {
```

here the `@SpringBootApplication` obviously implies  `@EnableAutoConfiguration` but I would like to avoid annotating each and every `*IntegrationTest` with this and instead configure it once on the `AbstractIntegrationTest`.

Is this fighting against spring-boot in any way or is there some way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create update your `AbstractIntegrationTest` abstract class to have a small inner configuration class e.g. `TestConfiguration` which is loaded using the `@Import(TestConfiguration.class)` annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {CoreConfiguration.class, RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class, JacksonAutoConfiguration.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
@Import(AbstractIntegrationTest.TestConfiguration.class)   // <---- import the configuration
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    // Any other applicable annotations e.g. @EntityScan
    static class TestConfiguration {

    }

    ....

}
```